# Parse a JsonVector

Tags: json, parsing, formatting

I'm not experienced with this topic, so i hope you guys might help me.

So i've written a Json file with the Json lib. Everything seems fine, the file has the structure i need to work with.

1.) I'm not sure of my json format is correct to be parseable.

EDIT---->Added new (correctly formatted) json file:

```
{
"Jobs": [

{

      "ExitCode" : "259",
       "Id" : "00000021",

   },

{

      "ExitCode" : "259",
      "Id" : "00000022",
   },

]
```

}

I think i miss something to identify the key/value pairs? Or could i still read those 2 fields seperately?

Used Code to generate:

```
PROT()<<"Writing File ----"<<endl;
StructType Struct;
Json::Value JsonVec(Json::arrayValue);

//TCHAR szBuf[MAX_PATH];
for(GP_ITERATOR(JobIt, JobMap))
{
    JobIt->second.Job.APIBind(Struct);
    Json::Value JsonJob;
    Struct.SaveToJSON(JsonJob);
    JsonVec.append(JsonJob);
}
JsonVec.append("Job:");
std::ofstream file_id;
file_id.open("test.txt");

Json::StyledWriter styledWriter;
file_id << styledWriter.write(JsonVec);

file_id.close();
```

Comment: Paste your code to http://jsonlint.com/ to validate it. It is not valid as-is. It has trailing commas after the last object members ("Id") and the last object (`}`).

Not really related to `C++` at all.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that i generated the file with c++ code. will add it to my description

Comment: It doesn't matter what you generated the JSON with really. You are asking if the JSON is valid or not, not about the C++. Hence the question is not about C++.

Comment: The actual question is: how can i read that generated file via c++.

Comment: Okay well the original JSON you have in the post is not valid (see the link). Once you have corrected that, then you should post a _specific_ question once you have tried to read the _valid_ JSON (if you have trouble). Also you need to re-add the C++ tag to the question when you edit it.

Comment: Alright, your answer already helped me. Will try to generate a valid file and read it.

Comment: Got the correct format now. Is there an easy way to read the json file i corrected?

Comment: You are using a library for that, so just read the documentation.